# How to detect uninitialized memory (C++, windows, VS2005)?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, memory, initialization

I'm looking for memory debugger for Windows which will be able to debug uninitialized memory.

There is a code snippet (C++):

```
class Temp{
public:
 Temp(double d) : m_double(d){};

 double m_double;
 float m_float;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 double temp;
 std::cout << temp <<std::endl;

 Temp temp2(2.0);
 std::cout << temp2.m_double <<std::endl;
 std::cout << temp2.m_float <<std::endl;

 int num1, num2;
 num1 = num2 + 1;

 return 0;
}
```

Desirable features:

- dynamic memory debugger, not static analysis tool
- GUI
- free
- integration with VS2005
- simple to use

Tried to use:

- Rational Purify v.7.0.0.0 build:6274
- Memory Validator v.5.12
- cppcheck - worked fine on given snippet but didn't helped on real big project

UPD: it seems that there is no way to find uninitialized memory in release mode with optimizations turned on with dynamic memory debugger. Going to try in debug mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've used Purify for all sorts of memory issues and it works pretty well. Downside is it's $$$$.

If it's at all an option, a Linux port of the backend to use valgrind which is also a great tool.

Comment: I used Rational Purify v.7.0.0.0 build:6274 on given code snippet and it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is more related to static code analyzers. I saw such warnings from visual studio with maximum warning level in project settings but I'm not sure about vs2005.

You can also try to use some tools from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97454/c-static-code-analysis-tool-on-windows) about code analyzers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I used cppcheck, it works fine for given snippet but didn't help on real big project, so I would prefer dynamic memory debugger, not static analysis tool.